# Inverse of a close-to-singular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, inverse, matlab, stationary-processes

I am working on a stochastic processes project. There, I am trying to solve the **Wiener-Hopf equation** to find the coefficients $c$ of a linear estimator:

$$Rc = r.$$

Here, $R$ is the autocorrelation matrix of a wide sense stationary process, and it is known that this kind of a matrix is positive definite. So I can always take the inverse and have:
$$c = R^{-1}r . $$

But, in MATLAB, $R$ is close to singular when size of $R$ is $30\times 30$, I get error:

> Warning: Matrix is close to singular or badly scaled. Results may be
>   inaccurate. RCOND =  4.519038e-18.

So when I simulate the mean square error on the growing size of $n$, it needs to always decrease, but after $n\geq 30$ I have increases as well and sometimes the variance is even negative (due to the imprecise inverse). So I want to fix this issue.

I know that this is a natural error to have due to computational precision and it has been asked a lot so far. But, the matrix has a special form, where $R(i,j)$ is equal to $R_X(|i-j|)$, i.e., the autocovariance between $X_i, X_j$. So the matrix has form:

$$\begin{bmatrix} R_X(0) & R_X(1) & R_X(2) \\
R_X(1) & R_X(0) & R_X(1) \\
R_X(2) & R_X(1) & R_X(0) \\ \end{bmatrix}$$

The diagonal is all ones since $R_X(0)=1$ and the matrix is symmetric. I thought maybe there is a linear-algebra trick since this matrix is a symmetric positive definite matrix with diagonal of all ones. It seems to be  a very easy matrix and I suspect if there is an  analytic way to take the inverse.

Note1: My process is a real valued process, that's why $R$ is a symmetric matrix. Normally the lower half corresponds to the complex conjugate of the upper half.

Note2: An example: when $n=3$, $R$ looks like:
$$\begin{bmatrix}   1.0000  &  0.2906  & -0.4020\\
    0.2906  &  1.0000   & 0.2906 \\
   -0.4020 &   0.2906   & 1.0000\end{bmatrix}$$

Note3: I tried to compute the Cholesky lower-half to compute inverse with that, of course, I have the same problem. Then, in order to compute the Cholesky decomposition, I followed the eigenvalue approach, but with a similar reason, I have found that some eigenvalues are negative. I think all these issues are similar in some sense... I also tried to solve a linear system via MATLAB's `c = linsolve(R,r)` property, but of course it uses the function inv(.) as well and leads to the same issue.

Note4: I think [this](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/37084) dsp.se answer is very relevant, but not useful.

**Final Note:** I am using `pinv(.)`, i.e., generalized Moore-Penrose inverse. It still is not accurate (the error is less weird though).